# How to update the scope of an appended html element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to interact with a scoped inside an appended html element on the page, can someone please show me how to update that scope?

```
var overlay = angular.element('<div id="flyout-overlay" class="page-overlay global" ng-show="testScope"></div>');
mainContent.append(overlay);

$timeout(function(){
    $scope.testScope = true; // how?
},500);
```

Comment: use $compile service in angularjs

Answer (score 1):

use $compile service

```
$compile(overlay);
```

here is the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler)

don't forget to add `$compile` dependency in the controller

doc says,

[image]

apply to your case,

`'<div id="flyout-overlay" class="page-overlay global" ng-show="testScope"></div>'`

1 : **compile** - $compile collect all the directives, for ex, it will collect `ng-show` directive

2: **link** - combine the directive with a scope.. , for ex, it will bind the `ng-show="testScope"` directive with the scope.

Comment: thank you but I am new to ng and might require some hand holding. i'm finding it hard to understand the documentation. can you please kindly spell out the answer for me?

Comment: @muudless create some plunk on plnkr.co , this will help people to help you

Answer (score 1):

@Kalhano gave the perfect answer but since you don't know about the $compile service, here is the code for you. Just a small change....

```
var overlayTmpl = angular.element('<div id="flyout-overlay" class="page-overlay global" ng-show="testScope"></div>');

var overlay = $compile(overlayTmpl)($scope);

mainContent.append(overlay);

$timeout(function(){
    $scope.testScope = true; // how?
},500);
```

in nutshell, $compile service compiles your html and links it to the scope you provided,

for better understanding read the angular documentation.